# Android loading json files from server

Tags: android, json, http, https, server

I am trying to read a json file in my android app from server with https:// some file are readable while other files are not. And if i change it to http:// i am able to read all file.

Files are named according to dates , so files name with date before 10-09-2015.json are readable but from 11-09-2015.json to 30-09-2015.json are not readable.
All files are having same permissions.

what is the difference between the two ways of accessing the files https://  and http://

Comment: What exactly do you mean not readble? What is the error. Have you tried typing in the urls into the browser?

Comment: yes, it is readable in browser but not in any android devices

Comment: what about using chrome on the device? Can you open those failing urls with it?

Comment: url is failing to load in device browser,it shows-  your connection is not private . And if remove s ie https and tried with http file is loading

Comment: clearly what you have is a TSL configuration issue. It's nothing to do with the code you have written

Comment: files are on amazon s3 server , so what changes should i do because some files are readable and some are not ?

Comment: That should be a separate question (not here but on superuser) please post full details of your TLS configuration, webserver logs etc.